# How can I calculate the union of a tagged set?

Tags: expression-manipulation

I want to calculate:

```
Union[envelope[1], envelope[2], envelope[3], envelope[4], 
envelope[5], envelope[6], envelope[7], envelope[8], envelope[9], 
envelope[10]]
```

These are just tagged sets and I had to do it this long way since I could not find another way that Found the union of

```
envelope[j]
```

for all j between 1 and 10

Is there a faster way to do this in the scenario I had to combine 100 sets in the future

Comment: `Union @@ (envelope /@ Range[10])`? Assuming that `envelope[j]` will evaluate to e.g. a list.

Comment: What do you mean by "tagged set"?

Comment: Labelled set I think

Answer (score 1):

I would call what you call a "tagged set" a set of indexed down values, but the terminology doesn't really matter. Such sets are suitable for use with functions such as `Table` and `Do`. Or you can map them over a range as MarcoB suggests in his comment.

Let's make an example.

```
SeedRandom[2]
Module[{n = 10, vals},
  choices = {yes, no, maybe};
  vals = RandomChoice[choices, n];
  Do[envelope[i] = vals[[i]], {i, n}];
  DownValues @ envelope]
```

[image: downvals]

Then

```
Union[envelope /@ Range[10]] === Sort @ choices
```

> `True`

and

```
Union[Table[envelope[i], {i, 10}]] === Sort @ choices
```

> `True`